Can someone explain to me why my coroutine works wrong?
Ok,so I do some of my learning stuff and I need my elevators to stop for a few secs
   private IEnumerator ReversePlatform()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2); 
        _AccuTime = 0;
        speed = -speed;
    }

I call it here and my elevators just start to shake and go up, they wont go down
        if (_AccuTime > _RunTime)
        {
            StartCoroutine("ReversePlatform");
        }
        else 
        {
            transform.Translate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

I need them to go up, stay there like 2 secs and then go down continuously

It's because StartCoroutine can start the same coroutine multiple times, you never added a check to make sure that ReversePlatform isn't already running:
private Coroutine reverseCoroutine;

private IEnumerator ReversePlatform()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2); 
     _AccuTime = 0;
    speed = -speed;
    reverseCoroutine = null;
}

if (_AccuTime > _RunTime)
{
    if (reverseCoroutine == null)
    {
        reverseCoroutine = StartCoroutine("ReversePlatform");
    }
}
else 
{
    transform.Translate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}



I need them to go up, stay there like 2 secs and then go down continuously

Why not just do it all in one routine then? It is always a bit weird mixing Update and repeating Coroutines
[Tooltip("Where to move to (worldspace)")]
[SerializeField] 
private Vector3 targetPosition;

[Tooltip("How fast to move (unit/s)")]
[SerializeField] 
private float moveSpeed;

[Tooltip("How long to wait on the start/end positions")]
[SerializeField] 
private float delay = 2f;

private Vector3 startPosition;

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    startPosition = transform.position;

    // This is totally fine for a Coroutine as long as you ensure you yield
    while(true)
    {
        // move to target with given speed
        yield return MoveTowards(transform, targetPosition, moveSpeed);

        // wait for delay
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        // move back to start with given speed
        yield return MoveTowards(transform, startPosition, moveSpeed);

        // wait for delay
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}

private static IEnumerator MoveTowards(Transform transform, Vector3 target, float moveSpeed)
{
    // Vector3 == uses approximation with precision 1e-5
    while(transform.position != target)
    {
        // every iteration moves one step towards the target without overshooting
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // "pauses" the coroutine, let Unity render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
 
    // to end with clean values
    transform.position = target;
}

Note: if you rather want to move in local space simply exchange all transform.position with transform.localPosition
